# How to structure an embedded mysql query to first select data that matches two columns and then match results to a third column?

Tags: mysql, passwords

I have a user password system where I need to 1) check a user password against two potential passwords stored in the database and 2) if a match is found make sure the user email matches the user email stored in the row that had the matching password.

This the current mysql I have to pull the unique user on login:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$u' AND password='$p' OR password_two='$p'";
```

This works in the vast majority of cases but fails when multiple users have the same passwords    - for example if multiple users have the password '123456'. I'm assuming this is because the AND OR setup I have above is incorrect.

I'm updated the sql query to the statement below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='$p' OR password_two='$p') WHERE email = '$u' ";
```

This query doesn't work for any users - Can someone help me identify where the query is going wrong?

Comment: What happens if you change it to `SELECT email FROM users`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking for:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$u' AND (password='$p' OR password_two='$p')";
```

Without the parenthesis, it's interpreted as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email='$u' AND password='$p') OR (password_two='$p')";
```

Comment: Ah - that's definitely it. Thanks for clarifying order of operations. Will accept when time limit comes off

Comment: No problem.  In almost all languages AND and OR will be equally weighted operations and thus will be parsed from left to right (in LR languages anyway).  They're also binary operators, meaning they group left to right for 2 elements.  That's why a and b or c means ((a and b) or c).  :)